# Error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined while creating Nested Json Object in Node Js

Tags: json, node.js, nested

```
myObj = {
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "vehicles": {
        "cars":["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"],
        "bikes":["Suziki", "BMW", "Yamaha"],
        "other":["Honda", "Scoda", "Bajaj"]
    }
 }
```

How to create that type of Nested Object?

```
var myObj = [];
"SELECT * FROM categories"; // done query and saved result into var res
for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++){
    myObj[i] = {};
    myObj[i].id = res[i].id;
    myObj[i].title = res[i].title;
    myObj[i].posts = {};

    "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = "+res[i].id+" AND user = John"; // done query and saved result into var nres
    for(var x=0; x<nres.length; x++){
        myObj[i].posts.john[x] = nres[x];
    } //sub for loop within main loop
    "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = "+res[i].id+" AND user = Johny"; // done query and saved result into var nnres
    for(var y=0; y<nnres.length; y++){
        myObj[i].posts.johny[y] = nnres[y];
    } //sub for loop within main loop
    "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = "+res[i].id+" AND user = Johns"; // done query and saved result into var nnnres
    for(var z=0; z<nnnres.length; z++){
        myObj[i].posts.johns[z] = nnnres[z];
    } //sub for loop within main loop

} //main for loop end
```

etc.,

I created that in `php`. but in `NodeJs`, it's showing error,

> Cannot read property 'posts' of undefined

this is what i need,

[
 {"id":"catagoryId", "title":"categoryTitle", "posts":{[postTitle, postContent, postTags],[],..., []}}, 
 {},
 ..., 
 {}
]

conclusion:
php is lot easier to write code, php manages variables itself.
But in JavaScript, need to declare Variables in correct manner, it's difficult.

Comment: I am to get above json in nodejs. Are you keeping above code in function and calling it.

Comment: Your above Node.js code **[is working fine](https://ideone.com/R7XOJv)**. Please post [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: get data from MySQL and create Nested Json Object, failed.

Comment: Please **edit** your post and paste example code which produces you the same error. Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: "PHP manages variables itself"? What does that even mean? Don't blame JS; it's not its fault you don't know it.

Comment: oh, i'm not blaming JS, i said my opinion, php is easier than js for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you think you are querying from the database, but you are **not calling MySQL**.

```
var res = "SELECT * FROM categories";
for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++){
    myObj[i] = {};
    myObj[i].id = res[i].id;
    myObj[i].title = res[i].title;
    myObj[i].posts = {};
```

`res` (and later `nres`) variables contain **strings**, actually the SQL commands you put in them. Therefore `res[i]` is a character, so it doesn't have `id`, `posts`, etc. keys.

---

The error says *"Cannot read property 'posts' of undefined"*. In your above code, `posts` property is accessed on `myObj[i]`, like this: `myObj[i].posts`.

According to the error, `myObj[i]` is `undefined`. But your code defines `myObj[i]` (`myObj[i] = {}`), so the problem may be in the code you didn't post.

Comment: sir, i'm not pasted my exact code, just trying to explain my problem. sql query is successfull, getting "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" error. Please Help about this issue.

Comment: Sir, I can't help if you don't post the necessary information. Please read [ask] and how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: oooh, sir, that's all what my code is except Sql query. I wrote all code except Sql query. Here is nothing about Sql, i added console.log(sql results), sql queries are successful. However, Thanks for trying to Help.

Comment: @juzraai Isn't that exact code in the OP? The line where you comment "create object here"? Immediately after the outer"for" loop?